# Java BigDecimal : How to fortmat BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I'm using BigDecimal for counting some big real number. Although I have try two method :
`BigDecimal.toString()` or `BigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros().toString()`, it still not sasitfy my requirement.

For example if I use `stripTrailingZeros`: `4.3000` becomes `4.3` but `4.0` becomes `4.0` not `4`.  Both above methods cannot sastisty those conditions. So, my question is : how to done it in java ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DecimalFormat` as follows:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("4.3000");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("4.0");

DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
f.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(false)
f.setMaximumFractionDigits(340);

System.out.println(f.format(a));
System.out.println(f.format(b));
```

which prints

```
4.3
4
```

As Bhashit pointed out, the default number of fractional digits is 3, but we can set it to the maximum of 340. I actually wasn't aware of this behaviour of `DecimalFormat`. This means that if you need more than 340 fractional digits, you'll probably have to manipulate the `string` given by `toString()` yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Look into the [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class. I think what you want is something like

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
// By default, there will a locale specific thousands grouping. 
// Remove the statement if you want thousands grouping.
// That is, for a number 12345, it is printed as 12,345 on my machine 
// if I remove the following line.
df.setGroupingUsed(false);
// default is 3. Set whatever you think is good enough for you. 340 is max possible.
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(340);
df.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(false);
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("1234.5678900000");
System.out.println(df.format(bd));
bd = new BigDecimal("1234.00");
System.out.println(df.format(bd));

Output:
1234.56789
1234
```

You can also use a [RoundingMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) of your choice. Control the number of decimal points to be shown by using the pattern provided to the [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) constructor. See the [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) documentation for more formatting details.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the behaviour he/she is looking for. I think they are looking to just strip all trailing zeros.

Comment: Updated the answer. Thanks for the comment. I mis-read the question.